# Getting split Items by Index from an IEnumerable list to add on certain ListView ColumnHeaders?

Tags: c#, linq

I have an iEnumerable list called Students read from a text file which was split by a linq query using a : delimiter. I am using a for loop, instead of a foreach loop because I want to add the List by Index to ListView SubItems. How would I go about grabbing a particular split Item from an iEnumerable list?

```
            var Students = File.ReadLines("C:\Folder\student_list.txt")
                .Select(line => line.Split(':'));

            // John:Smith
            // Adam:Turner
            // Abraham:Richards

            for (int i = 0; i < Students.Count(); i++)
            {
                // Listview already has 3 items, I want to add First and Last name of each
                // Item in Students List into ColumnHeader [1] and [2].

                // Before when using a foreach loop and no existing Listview Items, I was doing
                // foreach (var piece in Students)
                //     lvStudents.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new String[] { piece[0], piece[1] }))

                // How would I do the same up above, but for each SubItem using a for loop?      
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access `IEnumerable` by index. You have to use

```
string[] StudentItems = Students.ElementAt(i);
```

Another option would be the replacement of the `for` loop by `foreach`

```
foreach (string[] StudentItems in Students)
```

If you want to access your items by `[]` and avoid a `foreach`, you have to use a `ToList()` or `ToArray()`

```
string[][] Students = File.ReadLines(@"C:\Folder\student_list.txt")
                          .Select(line => line.Split(':'))
                          .ToArray();

for (int i = 0; i < Students.Count(); i++)
{
      string[] StudentItems = Students[i];
}
```